# No result when mapping an array of objects(React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

newbie here.

Cant seem to map the array below, which is the outcome of an axios fetch stored as "UserData.data".

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {_id: '6365763ec57b0ef06387f167', name: 'kalle', email: 'kalle@gmail.com', isAdmin: false, role: 'user', …}
1: {_id: '6365765dc57b0ef06387f16b', name: 'hasse', email: 'hasse@gmail.com', isAdmin: false, role: 'user', …}
2: {_id: '63657737c57b0ef06387f173', name: 'qwe', email: 'qwe@gmail.com', isAdmin: false, role: 'user', …}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Been trying this in my JSX, what im i doing wrong?

```
        <>
          <ul>
            {userData.data.map((data) => {
              <li key={data._id}>
                <Text>Test</Text>
              </li>
            })}
          </ul>
        </>
```

```
        <>
          <ul>
            {userData.data.map((data, i) => {
              <li key={data[i]}>
                <Text>Test</Text>
              </li>
            })}
          </ul>
        </>
```

Comment: you're getting an error?

Comment: we need your component code. all of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return the data

```
<>
  <ul>
    {userData.data.map((data) => {
      return (
        <li key={data._id}>
          <Text>Test</Text>
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
</>;
```

Comment: Simple as that, many thanks!